# Is it possible to design Android game(AndEngine) levels using XML?

Tags: android, andengine, level-design

I am developing a game. In the game there is a lot of levels. Is it possible to design game levels using XML? Or what are different ways to design game levels? Please help me.
Give some link or example so that i can understand easily...
Thanks

Comment: AndEngine has its own level format and utility class to use it. The question linked talks about the general idea on Android systems.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible. AndEngine has a Level loader that can do exactly what you need. I recommend [going through these tutorials.](http://www.matim-dev.com/tutorials.html) In the final tutorial, creating a whole game, [one of the chapters talks about level creating and loading.](http://www.matim-dev.com/full-game-tutorial---part-11.html) Look for a class named `SimpleLevelLoader`.